# Can't match values in between dashes

Tags: c#, sql-server

Why can't I match values in between dashes?
For example: 2016-05-20, when I tried to match number five using like function it will give no result even 05 but if I will match 2016 and 20 it will have a result. How do I match month in dates??

```
    public IEnumerable<NCABal> FindByNCABalDate(Int32 Month)
    {
        var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE NCABalDate LIKE '%"+ @Month +"%'";
        return this._db.Query<NCABal>(query).ToList();
    }
```

When I enter 5 or 05, no results will display.

Comment: What is ur expected output ?

Comment: What's the datatype of `NCABALDATE`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp - have you tried selecting just date parts?

Comment: if it finds the value which is in month, it will display a message working. That is for my testing purposes.

Comment: If `NCABalDate` is a `Date` or `DateTime` field - which the name would suggest - then you need to use `CONVERT` to first convert it to a `VARCHAR` before trying to use the LIKE operator.

Comment: Ehm, Int32 variables can't store the difference between 5 and 05.

Comment: @Felix: NCABalDate is in smalldatetime format which is in sql server db..

Comment: Use `DATEPART` or `MONTH()`.

Comment: Not every date time format support leading zero. You should search for 5 not 05

Comment: @csa: I already tried 5 but still not working. 2016 and 20 is working but when I tried to match 05 or 5 which is in between dashes then no results will display..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//for searching month
        var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE Datepart(mm,NCABalDate) = 5";
//for searching year
        var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE Datepart(yyyy,NCABalDate) = 2016";
//for searching day
        var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE Datepart(dd,NCABalDate) = 20";


//for searching month,year and day
            var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE Datepart(mm,NCABalDate) = 5 and Datepart(yyyy,NCABalDate) = 2016 and Datepart(dd,NCABalDate) = 20";
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. This is simple but very effective, :)

Comment: Do note that this will run three queries in a row which might be a bit taxing on the database.

Comment: @jitendragarg if you want to search using two conditions then you can join them into one query also e,g. for month and year write                                                           WHERE Datepart(mm,NCABalDate) = 5 and Datepart(yyyy,NCABalDate) = 2016

Comment: True. Whether it will be better than converting to string is a question that can't be answered without knowing the exact details. But, joining three clauses together is definitely better. Maybe update the answer for future readers?

Comment: @jitendragarg added code to search through day, month and year.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert(nvarchar(20),NCABalDate, 20) LIKE '%"+ @Month +"%'`

This will convert your datetime column to nvarchar, on which like will work fine. So, your query will become

`var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE Convert(nvarchar(20),NCABalDate, 20) LIKE '%"+ @Month +"%'";`

Comment: Do note, this will look for the value in whole string. So, if you are searching for month 10, year 2010 will also get selected.

Answer (score 0):

The value for month will go in as one character for values < 10 as you're not formatting it to be two characters. Try:

```
var query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NCA_Balance] WHERE NCABalDate LIKE '%"+ Month.ToString("D2") +"%'";
```